# How about calling system file manager to select folder instead of file in Android development?

Tags: android

Currently I can only select files. Is there any way to choose a folder?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
 startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
```

And you can also library [NoNonsense-FilePicker](https://github.com/spacecowboy/NoNonsense-FilePicker) for this operation.